# setObject() Method and aliasing

Tags: java, pointer-aliasing

I have a LINE class that has two attributes of type POINT (which is an object).

```
public class LINE {
private Point p1,p2;
}
```

If I make this statement, will it cause aliasing?

```
public void setP1(Point p1)
{
    this.p1=p1;
}
```

Or Do I have to create a new object, like that:

```
public void setP1(Point p1)
{
this.p1=new Object(p1);
}
```

Thanks in advnace.

Comment: I am assuming this is Java, so I marked it as such.

Comment: what you mean by aliasing ?

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry I didn't do it myself. Indeed java it is.

Comment: By aliasing I mean that two address in the stack points one object's values, which exposes the private attributes to the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it will cause aliasing.

My guess is that you're trying to create a copy of the object, than you want to instantiate a new `Point`.

That being said, if you Don't actually need to make a copy of the object, then the first one will do

so if you call it like

```
Line line = new Line()
line.setP1(new Point(/*params*/))
```

that's perfectly okay.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I thought. Is it okay to ask WHY would it cause aliasing? btw, I'm not trying to make a copy but to let the user edit the values of the LINE object

Comment: @user1941081  because `p1` isn't a point, its an address of a point.